# (node:10544) Accessing non-existent property '...' of module exports inside circular dependency - MongoDB (Mongoose) - NodeJS (Express)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, circular-dependency

I'm building an API for a mobile app with mongoDB (mongoose 6.3.0) in NodeJS (Express 4.17.3).

***The structure*** →
[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0s0go.png)

In this API I have :

- users
- bubbles

One user can take part of mutiple bubbles and a bubble can have multiple users in it.
A user has references to all the bubble_id that He takes part of.
A bubble has references to all the user_id that take part in the bubble.

***My user.model.js***

```
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    local: {
        email: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true,
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
    },
    bubbles: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Bubble',
        required: false,
    }],
}, {
    versionKey: false,
});
```

***My bubble.model.js***

```
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    dateCreation: Date,
    users: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true,
    }],
    userAdmin:{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true,
    }
}, {
    versionKey: false,
});
```

The thing is, I have created a method that add user to a bubble and updtate the "bubbles" key of my user, and i have the same for my bubble, I created a method that add bubble to a user and updtate the "users" key of my bubble.

***My user.queries.js***

```
const { addUserToBubble } = require("./bubbles.queries");

exports.addBubbleToUser = async (userId, body) => {
    const bubbleId = body.bubbleId;
    addUserToBubble(userId, bubbleId)
    
    return User.findByIdAndUpdate(
        userId, {
            $push: {
                bubbles: bubbleId,
            },
        }, {
            new: true,
        }
    );
};
```

***My bubbles.queries.js***

```
const { addBubbleToUser } = require('./users.queries')

exports.addUserToBubble = async (bubbleId, body) => {
    const userId = body.userId;
    addBubbleToUser(userId, bubbleId)
    
    return Bubble.findByIdAndUpdate(
        bubbleId, {
            $push: {
                users: userId,
            },
        }, {
            new: true,
        }
    );
};
```

I know there is something ronge in my structure but i can't figure it out.
When I launch my server there is a Warning :
*Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'addUserToBubble' of module exports inside circular dependency*

How can i solve my problem ?
Thank you for your time :)

Ok little update i made something like that and it works :

```
//method to add a user to a bubble update the bubble collection and user collection
exports.addUserToBubble = async (userId, body) => {
    const user = await User.findById(userId);
    const bubble = await Bubble.findById(body.bubbleId);
    const index = user.bubbles.indexOf(body.bubbleId);
    if (index > -1) {
        user.bubbles.splice(index, 1);
    }
    user.bubbles.push(body.bubbleId);
    bubble.users.push(userId);

    return Promise.all([
        Bubble.findByIdAndUpdate(
            body.bubbleId, {
                $addToSet: {
                    users: bubble.users,
                },
            }, {
                new: true,
            }
        ),
        User.findByIdAndUpdate(
            userId, {
                $addToSet: {
                    bubbles: user.bubbles,
                },
            }, {
                new: true,
            }
        ),
    ]);
}
```